# Error deploying to scratch org: "no QuickAction named FeedItem.RypplePost found"

Tags: scratch-org, scratch-org-definition-file

We're encountering an error deploying to a new scratch org:

> no QuickAction named FeedItem.RypplePost found

This is defined in a standard layout, `force-app/main/default/layouts/EmailMessage-Email Message Layout.layout-meta.xml`:

```
        <quickActionListItems>
            <quickActionName>FeedItem.RypplePost</quickActionName>
        </quickActionListItems>
```

The [Feeditem docs for RypplePost](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_feeditem.htm) says

> RypplePost—generated when a user creates a Thanks badge in Work.com.

Is there a scratch org that enables this? Or should I, as [other suggest](https://github.com/trailheadapps/build-apps-with-lwc/issues/4), delete these lines manually from the XML before deploying?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This metadata is related to Work.com.

I was able to resolve this error in a scratch org by adding the following to my scratch org definition:

```
"features": [
    "WorkThanksPref"
],
"settings": {
    "workDotComSettings": {
        "enableWorkThanksPref": true,
        "enableProfileSkills": true
    }
}
```